# aura:component JS controller stops working when I add Apex controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura

I'm new to Aura. A tutorial I'm following shows that adding the Apex class to the *controller* attribute in the aura:component element is how you can run Apex. However, when I change the *controller* attribute from the JS controller to the Apex controller, the JS controller stops working. Is this expected? How can I keep the JS controller referenced while also running Apex?

*Original JS controller referenced:*

```
<aura:component
  implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId"
  controller="TestController"
  access="global"
>
```

*Apex controller referenced:*

```
<aura:component
  implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId"
  controller="TestApexController"
  access="global"
>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `<aura:component controller="SomeApexClass">`, all @AuraEnabled methods in that Apex class are *imported* into your controller. That means if you have the following Apex:

```apex
@AuraEnabled public static Data init() {
...
```

And:

```js
({
  init: function(component, event, helper) {
  ...
```

These two methods will be in conflict, and you'll have problems calling the methods or wiring them to the markup. Make sure all of the function names are unique.

Answer (score 1):

The `controller` attribute is for [Apex controllers only](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_create.htm). You do not use the `controller` attribute to declare a JavaScript controller.

The JavaScript controller should be automatically wired to your component: the platform knows they go together because they are part of the [component bundle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_bundle.htm) and follow a specific naming pattern (`<componentName>Controller.js`).

Comment: That's what's confusing David. When I reference the Apex controller in the 'controller' attribute, the JS controller stops being referenced/stops working. I'm positive that the JS controller is a part of the component's bundle.

Comment: The same result occurs when removing the explicit 'controller' statement completely. So there is no implicit connection for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The Apex controller has to be referred in Aura component file.

Syntax:

```html
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId" controller="TestApexController" access="global">
    <!-- Optional component attributes here -->
    <!-- Optional HTML markup -->
    <div class="container"> 
        Hello world!
        <!-- Other components -->
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

In order to invoke methods in server side from controller.js or helper.js file

Syntax:

```js
var action = component.get("c.ApexMethod");
action.setCallback(this, function(response){
    var state = response.getState();
    if(state == 'SUCCESS') {
        alert(response.getReturnValue());
    }
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```